# How can I change the text-mode keyboard layout in Windows ME?

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout

In Windows ME GUI applications, I have my keyboard layout set to British (Shift-2 is `"`, etc.), but in the command-line mode, it seems to be reverting to the US keyboard layout (Shift-2 is `@`).  How can I change this keyboard layout to UK?

I think Windows 9x had "keyb uk" or similar to go in AUTOEXEC.BAT, but keyb seems to be gone now, and AUTOEXEC.BAT is no longer run at boot-time anyway.